# How to export (dump) WebSQL data

Tags: json, html, sqlite, google-chrome-extension, export

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that uses WebSQL to store historical data. 
Being WebSQL, the DB is stored on the client.

I'd like to add an option to export/import such data so that the user can share/use this data with other users, or with other PCs.

These are my first steps on a client-only database, so I wonder how to do this.
I was thinking to convert the DB to a huge `json` string that the user can copy/paste but doesn't look very user-friendly.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got a single table dump solution working on a [HTML5 database client](http://desalasworks.com/html5-databases-on-iphone/) I wrote a few days ago.

Check out http://html5db.desalasworks.com/script.js and scroll down to SqlClient.exportTable, this has an example that needs to be expanded to cover the whole database.

The steps are:

Step 1: Create the schema:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
```

Step 2: Get a list of tables:

```
SELECT tbl_name from sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```

Step 3: Loop through each of them and create an INSERT script with the results

```
transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM " + _tbl_name + ";", [], 
    function(transaction, results) {
        if (results.rows) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = results.rows.item(i);
                var _fields = [];
                var _values = [];
                for (col in row) {
                    _fields.push(col);
                    _values.push('"' + row[col] + '"');
                }
                _exportSql += ";\nINSERT INTO " + _tbl_name + "(" + _fields.join(",") + ") VALUES (" + _values.join(",") + ")";
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Hope this is useful.

**UPDATE JAN 2016 - WHOLE DB EXPORT**

I've got a JS websqldump library that you can download from github as well.

This one will export the *whole* database. Check out the code on:

https://github.com/sdesalas/websqldump

Usage as follows

```
websqldump.export({
  database: 'NorthwindLite',
  success: function(sql) {alert(sql);}
});
```

Comment: Ok. So your intention is to import the database, merely run through each line of the export and db.executeSQL. Nicely done. But it would be prudent to offer CREATE [database | table] IF NOT EXISTS in there before the flurry of insert statements.

Comment: Where does Step 1 play in?

Comment: Step 1 would be for creation of your database and will only give you the required [DDL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) (which you'd only execute straightaway once - and hopefully only have to, unless the definition of the source DB changes); while the data from step 3 is [DML](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) statements only.

Comment: @steven-de-salas I am interested in using your `//  Export current table as SQL script
SqlClient.exportTable = function() {` but how would I call this on my already created table with data? I init SqlClient.dbInit = { with my own settings. Regar,s

Comment: It would be nice of you to add to your answer how you would restore the backup...

Answer (score -1):

Not the most elegant way, yet most convenient.
Just paste the script in chrome debugger tools then call c(), and you should get the file.

```
var looongSQL = "";

var x = function (options) {
if (options.n < options.sqlTables.length) {
    onTheMove.openLocalDatabase().transaction(
        function (tx) {
            var sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + options.sqlTables[options.n];
            tx.executeSql(sqlStatement, [],
                function (tx, rslt) {
                    if (rslt.rows) {
                        for (var m = 0; m < rslt.rows.length; m++) {
                            var dataRow = rslt.rows.item(m);
                            var _fields = [];
                            var _values = [];
                            for (col in dataRow) {
                                _fields.push(col);
                                _values.push('"' + dataRow[col] + '"');
                            }
                            looongSQL += "INSERT INTO " + options.sqlTables[options.n] + "(" + _fields.join(",") + ") VALUES (" + _values.join(",") + ");\n";
                        }
                    }
                    options.n++;
                    x(options);
                }
            );
        });
}else
{
document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
            encodeURIComponent(looongSQL);
}

};
var c = function () {
onTheMove.openLocalDatabase().transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master;", [],
            function (transaction, results) {
                var sqlStatements = [];

                if (results.rows) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                        console.log(results.rows.item(i));
                        var row = results.rows.item(i);
                        if (row.sql != null && row.sql.indexOf("CREATE TABLE ") != -1 && row.sql.indexOf("__") == -1) {
                            var tableName = row.sql.replace("CREATE TABLE ", "").split(/ |\(/)[0];
                            sqlStatements.push('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  ' + tableName);
                        }if(row.sql != null && row.sql.indexOf("__") == -1){
                        sqlStatements.push(row.sql);}
                    }
                }

                for (var j = 0; j < sqlStatements.length; j++) {
                    if (sqlStatements[j] != null) {
                        looongSQL += sqlStatements[j] + ';\r\n';
                    }
                }

                transaction.executeSql("SELECT tbl_name from sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", [],
                    function (transaction, res) {
                        var sqlTables = [];
                        for (var k = 0; k < res.rows.length; k++) {
                            if (res.rows.item(k).tbl_name.indexOf("__") == -1) {
                                sqlTables.push(res.rows.item(k).tbl_name);
                            }
                        }
                        x({
                            sqlTables: sqlTables,
                            n: 0
                        });
                    });

            }
        );
    });
};
```

Another version that exports it as JSON

```
var looongSQL = "[\n";
var stringidiedLocalStorage = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
looongSQL += "/* 1 */ " + stringidiedLocalStorage + ",\n";
var x = function (options) {
if (options.n < options.sqlTables.length) {
    onTheMove.openLocalDatabase().transaction(
        function (tx) {
            var sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + options.sqlTables[options.n];
            tx.executeSql(sqlStatement, [],
                function (tx, rslt) {
                    if (rslt.rows && rslt.rows.length > 0) {
                        var _fields = [];

                        for (var col in rslt.rows.item(0)) {
                            _fields.push(col);
                        }
                        var insertTableSQL = "\"INSERT INTO " + options.sqlTables[options.n] + "(" + _fields.join(",") + ") ";
                        looongSQL += "/* " + options.count + " */ " + insertTableSQL;


                        for (var m = 0; m < rslt.rows.length; m++) {
                            var dataRow = rslt.rows.item(m);

                            var _values = [];
                            for (var col in dataRow) {
                                _values.push('\'' + dataRow[col] + '\'');
                            }
                            looongSQL += "SELECT " + _values.join(",");
                            if (m < rslt.rows.length - 1 && (m % 499 != 0 || m == 0)) {
                                looongSQL += " UNION ALL ";
                            }
                            if (m % 499 == 0 && m != 0) {
                                options.count++;
                                looongSQL += "\",\r\n/* " + options.count + " */ " + insertTableSQL;
                            }
                        }

                        looongSQL += "\",\r\n";
                        options.count++;
                    }
                    options.n++;
                    x(options);
                }
            );
        });
} else {
    looongSQL += ']';
    document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
        encodeURIComponent(looongSQL);
}

};
var c = function () {
onTheMove.openLocalDatabase().transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master;", [],
            function (transaction, results) {
                var sqlStatements = [];
                var count = 2;
                if (results.rows) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                        console.log(results.rows.item(i));
                        var row = results.rows.item(i);
                        if (row.sql != null && row.sql.indexOf("CREATE ") != -1) {
                            var objectType = row.sql.replace("CREATE ", "").split(/ |\(/)[0];
                            if (row.sql.indexOf("CREATE " + objectType + " ") != -1 && row.sql.indexOf("__") == -1) {
                                var objectName = row.sql.replace("CREATE " + objectType + " ", "").split(/ |\(/)[0];
                                sqlStatements.push('/* ' + count + ' */ "DROP ' + objectType + ' IF EXISTS ' + objectName + '"');
                                count++;
                            }
                            if (row.sql != null && row.sql.indexOf("__") == -1) {
                                sqlStatements.push('/* ' + count + ' */ "' + row.sql.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ") + '"');
                                count++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var j = 0; j < sqlStatements.length; j++) {
                    if (sqlStatements[j] != null) {
                        looongSQL += sqlStatements[j] + ',\r\n';
                    }
                }

                transaction.executeSql("SELECT tbl_name from sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", [],
                    function (transaction, res) {
                        var sqlTables = [];
                        for (var k = 0; k < res.rows.length; k++) {
                            if (res.rows.item(k).tbl_name.indexOf("__") == -1) {
                                sqlTables.push(res.rows.item(k).tbl_name);
                            }
                        }
                        x({
                            sqlTables: sqlTables,
                            n: 0,
                            count: count
                        });
                    });

            }
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you add arguments as to why your solution is "most convenient"?

Comment: you paste the script in chrome debugger tools call c(), and you get the file. Can't get any easier can it?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onTheMove is not defined