# How to copy populated sql database to phone's memory on first launch of the app?

Tags: android, sql, html, populate

I have an android app created using html5, jquery and phonegap and it stores entries into sql db.  I already have populated all data into the database.  Now, my question is how can I save this populated db and pack it with the apk file so that it'll just copy it to phones memory when the user installs the app?

I used Chrome and that is where I populated the data.

Comment: I just asked phonegap about this and they said it's not supported for android yet.  A suggestion is to migrate it by populating the database on first launch of the app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as exporting the data you have in your already populated database, I would refer you over to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948279/how-to-export-dump-websql-data) where they walk through how that might be done.

Once you have a dump of your database, I believe the easiest is to just manually populate the database the first time the app loads.  If you use a library like [html5sql.js](http://html5sql.com/) you will be able to do this easily and in basically one step.

Comment: ,i tried to port your html5sql.js to an android webview app,but it fails to run.It say's : result of expression 'html5sql.database' [null] is not an object  any idea?