# indexedDb backup in the cloud

Tags: javascript, backup, indexeddb

I would like my client web app to be able to backup the indexedDb database.
I do not have a webserver

i found this: [Exporting and importing IndexedDB data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798098/exporting-and-importing-indexeddb-data#answer-8205461) 
that says: "you can call an export callback passing the privileged array of objects representing a backup of your object store" 
so i have an array of objects in javascript which is my backup... 
how can I :
1. turn it to a file?
2. back it up in the cloud?

thank you for your help.

Michael (belgium)

nb: I would love to use dropbox api, i have found this http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-js/source/browse/#svn/trunk but doesn't know if it works ( will try it and let you know).

nb: Also i am planning to use pokki.com to deploy app on client's desktop.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

*Synchronizing. The API is not designed to take care of synchronizing with a server-side database. You have to write code that synchronizes a client-side indexedDB database with a server-side database.*